# Where do Images go in IONIC 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am just getting started with Ionic 2. I have created an `img` file in `app` inside it is a file logo.png. So I have created the following code:

css:

```
.getting-started {
  .logo {
      background-image: url(./img/logo.png);
  }
}
```

html:

```
  <ion-col offset-33 width-33 class="logo"><h1>Logo</h1></ion-col>
  <h3>Welcome to your first Ionic app!</h3>

</ion-content>
```

I know the css is working, as if I toggle the background color, I get the expected results. However, I don't get any background image, just the Logo text specified. Where should I have put the image file?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**EDIT**: As of Ionic 2 RC 0, the correct place to put your images is in `src/assets/img/` and the correct code to reference the image is `<img src="assets/img/myImg.png">`. Please see Ionic's [change log](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for RC0 (specifically #28).

---

As of right now, using the official Drifty Co. Ionic 2 [Conference App](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app) as a reference, images should be placed inside of the `www/` directory.

In my current Ionic 2 app, an image is located at `www/img/logo.png` and it is referenced in `app/pages/page_name/page_name.html` as `<img src='img/logo.png'>` and it works like a charm.

Currently using:

- ionic-angular v2.0.0-beta.6 (package.json)
- ionic-native ^1.1.0 (package.json)
- ionic-cli v 2.0.0-beta.25 (installed CLI)

Comment: The path of the image is not consistent on browser and the device. `<img src="assets/img/myImg.png">` does not work on neither. `<img src="/assets/img/myImg.png">` works only in browser, but `<img src="../assets/img/myImg.png">` works on both browser and actual device

Comment: In my HTML I had to use `assets/...` and inside CSS I had to use `../assets/...`

Comment: Is this relevant for images you have to download and display?

Comment: When using this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(HomePage) images are broken on devices.

Answer (score 23):

Using Ionic 2 beta 6, I handled this with a simple gulp task. I dropped my images in `app/assets/images` (this path is completely arbitrary). Then, I added the following task to `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task("assets", function() {
    return gulp.src(["app/assets/images/*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("www/build/images"));
});
```

You'll also need to update the `watch` and `build` tasks to include the new `assets` task in their calls to `runSequence()`. I don't believe the order of tasks in the sequence matters, in this case:

```
gulp.task("build", ["clean"], function(done) {
    runSequence(
        ["sass", "html", "fonts", "assets", "scripts"],
        function() {
            buildBrowserify().on("end", done);
        }
    );
});
```

If you output your images to the same path as I did, then you would reference your images in CSS from `../images/image-name.png` and in `<img>` tags from `build/images/image-name.png`. I have confirmed that these images are visible both from the browser and an Android device. I don't think it should be any different for iOS.

Comment: Agreed, this is the proper way to fix the issue, not the one accepted below. This way your project is properly built with only files needed, referencing only files in the build dir

Comment: If you're putting an image in the HTML then you'll need for example this path `<img src="build/images/myimage.jpg">`

Comment: This is answer is mostly out of date. Since moving from Beta 6, Ionic is moving away from Gulp as its build processor (using Rollup.js instead, although projects can be configured to use any build tools you'd like to use) and the file structure has changed considerably. Please see my answer below for more information and a link to the changelog.

Comment: Please note that now gulp is not used in ionic 2 any longer. I would go along with TheBrockEllis's answer

Answer (score 5):

The assets folder is the correct folder to place any media.
The location of my image:

fyi: if you dont have the folder, just create it

```
src > assets > img > background.png
```

**variables.scss**

```
.backgroundImage {
  background-image: url('../assets/img/background.png');
}
```

Then on the page I want to use it on:

**home.html**

```
<ion-content padding class="backgroundImage">

</ion-content>
```

You can also reference images the following way:

**home.html**

```
<ion-content padding class="backgroundImage">
    <img src="./assets/img/background.png" width="50%" />
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3):

www\lib\ionic inside ionic create one folder img
    now your path
    www\lib\ionic\img put your background image inside this img folder and in your

```
www\lib\ionic\css\ionic.css 
inside ionic.css find .view-container class and past this line.
.view-container {
background: url("../img/main_bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and if you not change in original ionic.css then in your inside www folder  inside any css file PAST THIS CODE                                                                                                       .scroll-content {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/home-bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% 100%;
     position: absolute;

Comment: I don't have a lib folder in www. I generated an IONIC2 project with the tutorial template

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found the answer on the IONIC forum. The images go in `www/img`, the paths to these is then:

```
url('../../img/appicon.png')
```

when referenced from css or html in a page folder which is in `pages` in `app`.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: Well, this worked when testing in the browser but not when packaging the app and running on a device...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292000/how-to-insert-image-in-ionic-2 for the correct fix.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem, I found a way, I don't know if is the best way, but it's work.

the images must go on a file sibling to build, inside folder `www`

- www
- build
- img

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution. Its using path relative to index.html and not template folder.

So we need use path without../

> src="img/John_Williams.jpg"

This works both on browser and apk

Answer (score 0):

I could not manage to make it work using a PNG file. It worked in the browser but when I build the app and deployed to a device it did not displayed.

Instead of fiddling with the Gulp file to understand what was going on, I figured out a simpler workaround :

**Inline the image into your HTML (or CSS) using a Data URI.**

There are many tools online such as [this one](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker) that will convert your PNG to a Base64 data URI.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is pool.jpg. Place it in /src/assets/img/pool.jpg

It needs to be in this directory (assets) as it is your source from where everything gets built.

Then stop your ionic serve command (Ctrl-C) or whatever you use.

Then delete EVERYTHING under www directory (it all gets rebuilt anyway).

Then restart your server by running 'ionic serve' again.

This will rebuild the directory with the images.
You can reference the image as  background-image: url('../assets/img/pool.jpg');
in your code.

I am using ionic 3 and it's a shame it doesn't pick up changes in the assets directory. IONIC should look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I 'm currently on ionic version 3.6 and I had to use this to work:
 `src="../../assets/img/myImage.jpg"`

The path `assets/img/myImage` didn't work for me

I hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Hi Guys i found a method add images to ionic v2

Create a images folder in "www" directory (www/images/) and add your all images in this path.

Then give your image path like this 
ex: for pages
src="images/logo.png"

in CSS
.ThemeColor{ background: url(/images/bg.png)};

That's it, works for me..

Thanks

Comment: I would not suggest adding the files directly into your build dir. They should be copied there as a part of the build process.

Comment: It will be replaced as soon as you do another build, and why is your css named "ThemeColor" when its referencing a image ?