# How to insert image in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm new on ionic 2 and i'm trying to insert an image, but i don't realize the real path. 
inside the file app/pages/getting-started/getting-started.html

```
<ion-content padding class="getting-started">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      <img src="img1.png" alt="">
      <img src="img/img1.png" alt="">
      <img src="../img/img1.png" alt="">
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Create a folder app/img and inserted an img1.png file inside it. and the same file inside the app/pages/getting-started folder.

So, this should be easy, but can't find anything inside the ionic docs.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do Images go in IONIC 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987213/where-do-images-go-in-ionic-2)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Personally, I would add the images wherever it makes more sense for you, in your case in the `app` folder, and add a Gulp task to copy the images to the `www/build` folder.

This is how my `gulpfile.js` lookslike: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/gulpfile.js

I have added this simple task to the `gulpfile.js` around line 66.

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
    gulp.src('app/**/**/*.png')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/build'))
});
```

Make sure the task `images` is added to the list of tasks that run before the `watch` task (the tasks listed inside [..], 3rd line). Also, make sure to run `gulpWatch` whenever you add a new image for example (line 7)

```
gulp.task('watch', ['clean'], function(done){
  runSequence(
    ['images','sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'scripts'],
    function(){
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.scss', function(){ gulp.start('sass'); });
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.html', function(){ gulp.start('html'); });
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.png', function(){ gulp.start('images'); });
      buildBrowserify({ watch: true }).on('end', done);
    }
  );
});
```

Alternatively, you can use this gulp plug-in https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-gulp-image-task and `require` it and use in your `gulpfile.js` similar to the other tasks such as `copyHTML`, `copyFonts`, `copyScripts` here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/gulpfile.js

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: How to use gulpfile.js to load a folder in device. because i am added folder which consist one image and json file. can you help how to add gulpfile to load my folder in device ionic 3.

Answer (score 37):

Tested with Ionic2.rc2:

The default build takes the images under src/assets/img and puts it under assets/img. In order to reference them from the scss files you need to go up a folder:

```
background: url('../assets/img/sports-backgrounds.jpg');
```

That's the only way I got it to work, even even leaving out the '../' worked on the browser while testing.

At the same time, if you're referencing the images from the view (html files), here's what works for me:

```
<img src="assets/img/logo-image-for-login-page.jpg"
```

Ionic 2 is somewhat unstable so there're still some quirks that need to be ironed out.

Good luck.

Comment: The ONLY correct answer for this question. Saved me hours. Thank you.

Comment: The `<img src="assets/img/..." />` does not seem to work in Ionic View app?

Comment: yeah, i'm having the same issue. When i add img tag, my app wont render.

Answer (score 8):

Since Ionic2 apps ES2015 js complies down to normal javascripts(ES5), you should have your images etc in the `www/build` folder

So create a folder `www/build/img` and add your images in there. Then you should be able to access it as `build/img/img1.png`

**EDIT**

Adding an answer to the question `i don't undestand why you need to work the code in app folder but put insert the images into www folder`

---

Ionic2 uses latest javascript standards such as ES2015 (ES6) , Typescript (Optional) . This allows us to write code in slightly different way than we do in normal javascript. With classes modules etc.

However still most of the browsers doesn't support this new javascript standards , hence Ionic uses a concept called [transpiler](http://dailyjs.com/2015/02/26/babel) to change the new javascript code to old fashion javascript code so that browsers can understand.

So with Ionic2 even though u code in the app folder ultimately it compiles and runs from the www folder. Technically speaking your ionic app still runs from the www folder, because of that reason you have to add your images to the www folder.

Comment: if that works, keep your images anywhere and give full path starting with `/` (root) and it should work. ie:[ image folder `www/xyz/img` and `<img src="/xyz/img/img1.png">` ]  , or make use of `<base>`

Comment: Thanks, i don't undestand why you need to work the code in app folder but put insert the images into www folder

Comment: i done as said but i get err in my console http://192.168.1.2:8100/www/build/img/image.png 404 (Not Found) @BraianMellor

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan where do you put the image? Can you write the path and the img source?

Comment: ionic2  image is in www/build/img file name is image.png, and in my browser i get a small image like icon but i don,t get the actual image <div text-center>
        <img style="height: 100%; width: 20% "  src="/www/build/img/image.png">
</div>

Comment: You don't want the /www part, try using src="build/img/image.png" instead.

Comment: @BraianMellor, little late to the party, however I updated my answer explaining why you should add images to www folder. THT :)

Comment: @sameera207 like your answer even more.

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan without the www un your src. Thanks guys

Comment: @BraianMellor check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382853/could-not-able-to-view-image-in-ionic-2

Comment: Yes and as the answer said, the link goes to www folder. And the common way is to put in inside the build folder.

Comment: Please see my answer for a better way to work with image using Gulp

Answer (score 2):

I was having same problem, I found a way, I don't know if is the best way, but it's work.

the images must go on a file sibling to build, inside folder www 
 
- www  
 
-- build  
 
-- img

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me.

Inserted `<img src="../../assets/imgs/logo.png" alt="couldn't load">` to home.html file located inside app/src/pages/home directory.

Location of the image is app/src/assets/imgs/logo.png

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your img folder in the www folder and you're done! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Only you must create **img** folder in www. --> www/**img** (put images in the folder...)

Then in page (html) your must reference `<img src="img/logo.png" />`

I test in **Chrome Browser**, **App Android** and **App Ios** . (Ionic 2.0.0-beta.11)

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using the Ionic Beta Latest ionic@beta11.

---

To resolve this problem you can append the images absolute path in the copy.config.js file which will be residing in the node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config folder

You can append this file for specific folder by providing source (src) and destination (dest) path.

Hope this helps for copy the images folders to www/build/images folder

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src = "assects/img/abc.png"/>

img- file name
```

image should be stored in assects