# Could not able to view image in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to add image in my app, i stored my image locally in my  myApp/www/build/img.image.png

my html is

```
<div text-center>
        <img style="height: 100%; width: 20% "  src="/www/build/img/image.png">
        <p >Powered By yokesh</p>
    </div>
```

i get an output like this

[image]

And in my console i get

[image]

my ionic info

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.6
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.4.3
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Could someone help me to fix this

Comment: Can you get (and post) the errors from the browser console using Ionic?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer check it once

Comment: Hi Yokesh Varadhan. Try including src="img/image.png" alone in your html

Comment: Still i get the same output @Aish123

Comment: Create a variable in your .ts file as this.myimg = "img/image.png" and use the variable in img as data-src={{myimg}}.

Comment: @Aish123 still no image appears

Comment: Which version of angular 2 u are using? could you post your ts and html together. Also try using only src instead of data-src.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112663/discussion-between-yokesh-varadhan-and-aish123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without `/www/build/`

```
<div text-center>
        <img style="height: 100%; width: 20% "  src="img/image.png">
        <p >Powered By yokesh</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: i dont get that image

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to wrote down one part of my answer. I am usually storing images outside the build folder. For example, I create img folder inside www folder, place images there and in that case my code example should work. I am not storing static images inside of build because gulp is clearing that folder and I was afraid that images could got deleted by gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Start by storing your image in the following directory: create the folder "img" if it is not there

```
[appname]/www/img/image.png
```

Then Your div should look like this:

```
<div text-center>
    <img style="height: 100%; width: 20% " src="img/image.png">
<p>Powered By yokesh</p>
</div>
```

I also suggest storing all your css in `[pageName].scss` file. with ionic2 you have no excuse

Answer (score 0):

for ionic2, stop tampering with your www folder. The www folder content is always auto-generated by the build process. Always add your images at.

```
[appname]/src/assets
```

For your case, the image.png will be `[appname]/src/assets/img/image.png`

then the html src will look like :

```
 <div text-center>
        <img style="height: 100%; width: 20% "  src="assets/img/image.png">
        <p >Powered By yokesh</p>
    </div>
```