# Ionic 2 - No styles or images appearing in ionic view app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created an app using ionic 2 that looks fine when testing in Chrome. However I uploaded to the client, and tried to view using ionic view -- and all the css and images were missing. I may have the wrong paths, or maybe the assets aren't being uploaded, but not really sure how to debug it. For example, in my index.html page, I have the following link

```
<link href="/css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This works fine in chrome, but not in ionic view.
Also, the image paths are not appearing, for example

```
<img src="/images/btn_play_again.png" />
```

This works fine in chrome, but I'm getting a broken image in ionic view.
Any idea how to figure this out?

Comment: I've had the same problem but with building as an `apk` file. Reinstalling `@ionic/app-scripts` fixed this issue for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your paths are invalid. Please make sure that the following files exist in **www** directory of your project structure:

```
css/ionic.app.css
images/btn_play_again.png
```

If they do not exist then please add them into folder **src/assets**, which guarantees that both files shall be copied into the folder **www** after each compilation.

Comment: This works -- I was had to move the images into the src/assets folder and reference therm there as a relative path -- as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952214/correct-way-to-use-image-assets-in-ionic-2 . The one thing I still have issues with is referencing images as css backround-images -- url('assets/img/name.png') isn't working

Comment: Path should be relative to the generated file **main.css** under the folder **www/build**. Hence the correct path should be **url('../assets/img/name.png')**

Answer (score 2):

Make your paths relative instead of absolute. Your local paths are not the same as the app's paths.

Probably it will be just a matter of removing the starting slash:

```
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<img src="images/btn_play_again.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say why thats happening without seeing your file structure, but I would try to use [Ionics directives](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/img/Img/) with respect to the image problems, which could also be part of your href css problems.

```
<ion-img src="images/btn_play_again.png" />
```

For the styling, I am not sure why you have that link to begin with. Ionic builds all your scss/sass to *build/main.css*

```
<link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I would say just re-generate your project using the ionic cli. Dont worry about changing the index.html file. Or show me your file structure.

Answer (score -1):

From 2.0.0-rc.0 (2016-09-28) release the images are handled in a different way.

1:  Place all the images in `src/assets/img`

2:  In the pages HTML file image path would look like  `<img src="assets/img/someImage.png">`

3:  In component specific scss file the path will look like  `url('../assets/img/someImage.png');`

While implementing the above DO NOT add platform  to your project. If you have already added your platform - please run

`ionic platform remove <android or ios >`

once the platform is removed - please add platform afresh with

```
ionic platform add <android or ios >
```

Now run `ionic serve` or `ionic build <platform>` - the compilation process will copy the images into the `www` folder.

I found a post at https://digitaliq.jimdo.com/ionic-framework/ionic-2/using-images/

This helped me to sort issues.

Comment: @FelixSFD Sorry for being in hurry. I placed the entire solution I found there. Hope it is ok now.