# Images in ionic 2 scss files

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

According to [Where do Images go in IONIC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987213/where-do-images-go-in-ionic-2) and the [ionic changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#modifying-your-existing-project) I should be putting images in `src/assets/img`.

This does work for `<img src="assets/img/...`

However, it does *not* work for images referenced in scss files. So for example I may have `pages/login/login.html` that has the above image and that works, but then in `pages/login/login.scss` I have:

```
border-image: url("assets/img/...
```

Based on some debugging it seems like it's trying to load the image from `www/build/assets` in the CSS files, but `www/assets` in html.

Is there something else I need to do to get image assets loading properly in the scss files?

Comment: have you tried `url(../assets/img/...)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must refer to your image a directory above the traditional working directory, as your stylesheet is nested within the directory that the page is traditionally accessed.

For example, to set the background image of a `<div>` tag such as  `<div class="cover"></div>`, you would implement the following in your `.scss` file for that page.

```
.cover{
    background-image: url('../assets/img/bg.jpg');
}
```

**Edit:**
The Ionic *Super Starter* repository on [Github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-super/) is meant to show you some of the page layouts and best practices for your Ionic 2 project.

If you take a look at the [`.scss` stylesheet for the landing/welcome page](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-super/blob/c5b43dcbff2790f9690af73215eefc66c962f581/src/pages/welcome/welcome.scss) you can see that the background image is referenced in the same way with the following line:

```
     background: url('../assets/img/splashbg.png') no-repeat transparent;
```

Comment: Is there anything in any documentation that indicates this?

Comment: @ExplosionPills take a look at the edit I just made to the original answer for more support. In the Ionic 2 sample from driftyco and best practices application you can see that the background image is referenced in the same way.